# Not enough quote symbols in php echo to run javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to add a mouse over photo into my member database, but I can't seem to swich the quote symbols in such a way as to make this work.

Currently I have

```
echo '<tr>
        <td>
          <a href="users.php?edit='.$id.'">'
          .$name.'<img src="images/pix.png" 
          id="place-holder-1" 
          style="zindex: 100; position: absolute;" /></a>
        </td>
```

And I'm trying to implement

```
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='http://fit.physics.ucdavis.edu/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=cache&media=shared:no-avatar.jpg';"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='http://i.imgur.com/6vc0SJg.png';"
>
    foto<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6vc0SJg.png" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute;" />
    </a>
```

Demo
http://pietrow.net/foto.html

Comment: Do. Not. Use. Inline. Javascript. )))

Comment: You can escape a quote character in a string with a backslash, like `'\''` is a string containing a single quote.

Comment: Read up on HEREDOC strings in PHP.

Comment: Your `echo` is missing a `'` at the end. Otherwise your quotes all match up.

Comment: You are missing ' in the ending of echo

Comment: Your *CURRENTLY HAVE* and *TRYING TO IMPLEMENT* are nothing like each other. **GIVE IT A TRY YOURSELF** or post what you have currently tried and failed with.

Comment: I got everything working except the onmouseover and onmouseout scripts, but as they use both ' and " I can't put them in. That's the prob.

Comment: You just have to escape them. Something like `echo '...<a ... onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'place-holder-1\');...`

Comment: Ah that works! Thanks :) 
Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use quotes inside quotes you have to escape them, so it would be something like:

```
echo '<a onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'place-holder-1\').src=\'http://fit.physics.ucdavis.edu/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=cache&media=shared:no-avatar.jpg\'"     
         onmouseout="document.getElementById(\'place-holder-1\').src=\'http://i.imgur.com/6vc0SJg.png\'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

try escaping single quotes like this:

```
echo '<tr>
    <td>
      <a href="users.php?edit='.$id.'">'.$name.'<img src="images/pix.png" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute;" /></a>
    </td>
    <!-- your other stuff if any -->
    <a onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'place-holder-1\').src=\'http://fit.physics.ucdavis.edu/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=cache&media=shared:no-avatar.jpg\';" onmouseout="document.getElementById(\'place-holder-1\').src=\'http://i.imgur.com/6vc0SJg.png\';">foto<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6vc0SJg.png" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute;" />
</a>'
```

Also when dealing with large portion of html in PHP you may use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) it will make your life easier